# How to set up script that will automatically copy a row from sheet 1 to sheet 2 with specified background color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to extract rows with bg color yellow from sheet 1 to sheet 2 in google sheets. A script, macro or button would be great so I only have to set it up once and when a row is highlighted it will automatically be copied to sheet 2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function moveYellow() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var v=rg.getValues();
  var b=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    if(b[i][0]=='#ffff00') {
      csh.appendRow(v[i]);
      //sh.deleteRow(i+2-d++);
    }
  } 
}
```

This copies only columns A,C,E

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var v=rg.getValues();
  var b=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    if(b[i][0]=='#ffff00') {
      csh.appendRow(v[i].map(function(c,i){if(i==0 || i==2 || i==4){return c;}}).filter(function(e){return e}));
      //sh.deleteRow(i+2-d++);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: For delete row it will not delete the original row in the first sheet right?

Comment: I changed it so that it will not delete the top row in Sheet1.

Comment: Do I also need to enter variables for lines 2,3,4,5,6,and 7?

Comment: I think you just need to make sure the sheet names are correct

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 5, file "Code")

Comment: There's not much left. The error indicates that the `var sh` is null and there's nothing wrong with the commands so it has to be something wrong with the names.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JThdbBuwC3Y6T0G8-M5ZSc-FUDxCDRSbjGYLcZLMrQM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just as I none of your sheet names match either sheet 1 or sheet 2.  That's a problem.  You need to change the sheet names in the script.

Comment: Ok no errors but now I would like only to copy the rows not delete them. Also copy only columns A, C and E

Comment: Thanks cooper! Hopefully this will help someone else looking to do something similar.